# Drop duplicates from tuple Dateset in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, tuples

I'm having trouble with dropping duplicated rows in tupled dataset `Dataset[(LeftDs, RightDs)]`

Trying to join two datasets like this:

```
val comparableDs = leftDs.joinWith(
   rightDs,
   fuzzyMatch(leftDs.col("name"), rightDs.col("officialName"))
)
```

I want to drop duplicates for two fields:

```
val resultDs = comparableDs.dropDuplicates("_1.name", "_2.officialName")
```

But getting this error:
`Cannot resolve column name "_1.name" among (_1, _2);`

This is a schema of the `comparableDs`:

```
root
 |-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- officialName: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I write column parameters to `dropDuplicates` method for this schema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you use joinWith, the dataframe you get has only two columns. And Spark doesn't support drop duplicates for nested column.

You can use join to flatten the columns, instead of joinWith, which you can specify the column you want to dropDuplicates for.